# How to monitor Jupyterlab notebook in SageMaker Studio?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, amazon-sagemaker

I am wondering if there is a way to monitor the logs of a SageMaker Studio notebook. The notebook instances (16GB of memory) are running fine but sometimes the kernel dies loading big datasets. The only output from the UI is that the kernel has changed from `busy` to `idle` but there is no way to actually see the logs of the running notebook's kernel and why it died.

I did the test by switching to a bigger instance (128GB of memory) and the dataset was loaded correctly. Running `df.info()` showed that the dataset was only using **4.0GB** of memory, which should be loaded fine with a 16GB instance.

So I would like to know if there is a way to monitor or see the running logs of the current notebook AND or if it is necessary to change an environment of the notebook to allow bigger datasets to be loaded without killing the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Few things to consider:

1. You cannot access the instance logs in SageMaker Studio.
2. You dont need to change instance type for 4 GB of dataset.
3. The kernel is running through a [Studio image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/notebooks.html). The image is running a container on an EC2 instance You can check the running status of the app in the both Studio and  as well. So when you switch instance type, a new instance is spun up and the image is run on the new instance and kernel is rendered, hence the state of the kernel is lost.

Check out Studio screenshot below:
[image: Studio]

Check out Studio screenshot below:
[image: SageMaker console]

I also have a question:

1. Why you want to load the data in the notebook memory? Is it for Exploratory data analysis? Do you know you can use [SageMaker Data Wrangler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/data-wrangler.html) or [SageMaker Processing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/processing-job.html) to perform data pre processing?

Let me know if you need more info.

[Edit]: If you want full control over dependencies during pre processing and want to build a repeatable container that you can run many times with your code, SageMaker Processing is your best bet. You can read more about it here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/use-your-own-processing-code.html

There are also tons of examples around it available in the SageMaker official examples repo: https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/tree/main/sagemaker_processing

Comment: Thank you Vikesh! I'm mostly using the notebooks to load the data for exploratory analysis and run transformations on the data, hence I normally load (either full or in chunks) the data into the kernel's memory. I didn't know about these services tbh, but looking at Data Wrangler for example, I am not sure if I can process the data with let's say spacy, as I need to download and install dependencies on the instance where the transform functions are running. Am I wrong with this assumption? and if so, is there a way I can build the processing image and use it in Data Wrangler?

Comment: Currently Data wrangler supports custom transformations using PySpark, Pandas, and PySpark SQL only. If you have custom dependencies, you can build you own SageMaker Processing(another service ;)) container and run it with your own dependencies, script and what not.https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/use-your-own-processing-code.html